# Expected value: Showing $[\Bbb E(X)-\Bbb E(Y)]^2 \geq 2 \cdot \Bbb{Cov}(X,Y)$

Tags: probability

The original question is to show that for any Random variables $X,Y$ and $0\leq p \leq 1$

$$p\Bbb V(X)+(1-p)\Bbb V(Y) + p(1-p)[\Bbb E(X)-\Bbb E(Y)]^2 \geq p^2 \Bbb V(X)+(1-p)^2 \Bbb V(Y) +2p(1-p) \Bbb{Cov}(X,Y)$$

I tried to focus on showing $[\Bbb E(X)-\Bbb E(Y)]^2 \geq 2\Bbb{Cov}(X,Y)$, but it didnt work for me..

Any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: What happens if you set $X=Y$ in "$(E(X)-E(Y))^2\ge 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$"?

Comment: haha, my mistake it should have been E(X)^2+E(Y)^2

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substracting the RHS from the LHS and simplifying by the nonnegative factor $p(1-p)$, one sees that the original question is solved as soon as
$$
\Bbb V(X)+\Bbb V(Y)+[\Bbb E(X)-\Bbb E(Y)]^2 -2\Bbb{Cov}(X,Y)\geqslant0.
$$
The fact that
$$
\Bbb V(X)+\Bbb V(Y)-2\Bbb{Cov}(X,Y)=\Bbb V(X-Y)\geqslant0,
$$
concludes the proof.